# Unix text processing

Tags: text-processing, text

2 text files. I have to find the uniq values from the 2 text files and take the output in 3rd file with the filename along with uniq values.
For eg
a.txt

```
1
4
3
```

b.txt

```
2
1
7
```

Output

```
File.out
b.txt 2
a.txt 3
a.txt 4
b.txt 7
```

I tried the below command

```
cat a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq -u >>file.out
```

But it is printing only values, not getting file names

Comment: Can you explain how to determine the order of lines in the output file? Sorted numerically?

Comment: Order is not needed in output file.. I need filename along with uniq values in output file . When I cat output file I want to know the uniq values are from a.txt or b.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could prepend the filenames using Awk, then sort + uniq the second field:

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME,$0}' a.txt b.txt | sort -k2 | uniq -uf1
b.txt 2
a.txt 3
a.txt 4
b.txt 7
```